# Error with Rails Edge/4 `require': cannot load such file -- thread_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Following ths instructions here for getting an app running off Rails Edge to test Rails 4:
[What is the best way to generate a Rails app using edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346720/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-rails-app-using-edge)
and
[How to create Edge rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821077/how-to-create-edge-rails-application)

But running into this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- thread_safe (LoadError)
```

Using the command:

```
rails new Edge --edge --skip-bundle --database=postgresql --skip-test-unit --skip-index-html
```

A checkout of Rails master bin dir is on my path.

I am using rbenv with ruby 1.9.3p327.

I have cleared all my installed gems out, just running bundler.

Rails 3.2.9 works fine on my system, have an app in active development.

Comment: Might be this link is useful https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8589

Comment: Try installing `thread_safe` gem

Comment: Thanks @amar, found that link right after I posted this and it did indeed solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is not having the rails gems installed (when installing via rubygems, dependencies are automatically resolved.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8589

Need to go into the cloned rails dir and run "bundle install", which will pull in the necessary gems.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. While doing a bundle in the rails directory I found the invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII problem, which can be easily fixed, as pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650562/invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-when-trying-to-start-rails-app-with-phusion-pa, by adding if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end on the top of the Gemfile in rails dir.