# Heroku Rails application cannot load rails/commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have pushed an update to my Rails 4.0.1. application on Heroku and got the following error when the application starts:

> 2013-12-31T02:59:18.626397+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadErro
>   r)
>
> 2013-12-31T02:59:18.626397+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `'

Note that i tried rolling back the code change I was trying to push and as of now the same code snapshot that ran perfectly well on Heroku a few hours ago gets this error. Also, the same code snapshot runs well on my local rails server.

Has anyone ever seen this error and can advise?

**Edit:** I did dome more attempts. It seems that the exact same code base deploys successfully onto another Heroku application, so the question remains how can I restore the original application to its working state?

Comment: There already a similar question  in SO for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098983/error-with-rails-edge-4-require-cannot-load-such-file-thread-safe

Comment: Thanks, already saw that post and what it suggests isn't helpful in my case. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that what doesn't work for me is rails/commands, not thread_safe. Besides, The same set of gems was successfully deployed some time before so I can't figure out what went wrong.